# How to deal with empty JSON object?

Tags: json, flutter, api, http, dart

I'm working with an API that returns empty list when the app start. Its showing the following error in the particuler line:   `productList: List<ProductList>.from(json["ProductList"].map((x) => ProductList.fromJson(x))),`

How can I handle this error? I saw some solution they providing an empty list[]. If you just tell me what syntax I should use here to handle this kind of error...

For this error my App loading  infinite time sometimes.

[image: error]

My Model class

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

MyCartItemListModel myCartItemListModelFromJson(String str) =>
    MyCartItemListModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String myCartItemListModelToJson(MyCartItemListModel data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class MyCartItemListModel {
  MyCartItemListModel({
    required this.status,
    required this.message,
    required this.userId,
    required this.cookieVal,
    required this.totalItem,
    required this.cartProductTotal,
    required this.shippingCharge,
    required this.cartTotal,
    required this.productList,
  });

  int status;
  String message;
  String userId;
  String cookieVal;
  String totalItem;
  String cartProductTotal;
  String shippingCharge;
  String cartTotal;
  List<ProductList> productList;

  factory MyCartItemListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      MyCartItemListModel(
        status: json["Status"],
        message: json["Message"],
        userId: json["UserId"] ??"",
        cookieVal: json["CookieVal"],
        totalItem: json["TotalItem"],
        cartProductTotal: json["CartProductTotal"],
        shippingCharge: json["ShippingCharge"],
        cartTotal: json["CartTotal"],
        productList: List<ProductList>.from(json["ProductList"].map((x) => ProductList.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "Status": status,
        "Message": message,
        "UserId": userId,
        "CookieVal": cookieVal,
        "TotalItem": totalItem,
        "CartProductTotal": cartProductTotal,
        "ShippingCharge": shippingCharge,
        "CartTotal": cartTotal,
        "ProductList": List<dynamic>.from(productList.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class ProductList {
  ProductList({
    required this.cartId,
    required this.productId,
    required this.productName,
    required this.productImage,
    required this.productSize,
    required this.productColor,
    required this.productRate,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.productTotal,
  });

  String cartId;
  String productId;
  String productName;
  String productImage;
  String productSize;
  String productColor;
  String productRate;
  String quantity;
  String productTotal;

  factory ProductList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ProductList(
        cartId: json["CartId"],
        productId: json["ProductId"],
        productName: json["ProductName"],
        productImage: json["ProductImage"],
        productSize: json["ProductSize"],
        productColor: json["ProductColor"],
        productRate: json["ProductRate"],
        quantity: json["Quantity"],
        productTotal: json["ProductTotal"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "CartId": cartId,
        "ProductId": productId,
        "ProductName": productName,
        "ProductImage": productImage,
        "ProductSize": productSize,
        "ProductColor": productColor,
        "ProductRate": productRate,
        "Quantity": quantity,
        "ProductTotal": productTotal,
      };
}
```

My json Response:

```
   {
    "Status": 1,
    "Message": "",
    "UserId": "2",
    "CookieVal": "",
    "TotalItem": "4",
    "CartProductTotal": "1767",
    "ShippingCharge": "50",
    "CartTotal": "1817",
    "ProductList": [
        {
            "CartId": "450",
            "ProductId": "10622",
            "ProductName": "     Kids Baby Leggings Pink",
            "ProductImage": "https://sleepkart.co.in/productimage/zb9diak47ocm0q957itf_1.jpg",
            "ProductSize": "L",
            "ProductColor": "#fdc291",
            "ProductRate": "190",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "ProductTotal": "190"
        },
        {
            "CartId": "449",
            "ProductId": "10623",
            "ProductName": "Kids Baby Leggings Green",
            "ProductImage": "https://sleepkart.co.in/productimage/ogr137q1kjr9fiqwdipd_1.jpg",
            "ProductSize": "L",
            "ProductColor": "#42d19a",
            "ProductRate": "193",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "ProductTotal": "193"
        },
        {
            "CartId": "438",
            "ProductId": "10661",
            "ProductName": "Night Suit for Women",
            "ProductImage": "https://sleepkart.co.in/productimage/4jcrpnqw655vg7yoyvun_1.jpg",
            "ProductSize": "L",
            "ProductColor": "#f2be02",
            "ProductRate": "975",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "ProductTotal": "975"
        },
        {
            "CartId": "437",
            "ProductId": "10575",
            "ProductName": "Men's Navy Blue Bermuda",
            "ProductImage": "https://sleepkart.co.in/productimage/zn8oqvspajuks9u1pre4_1.jpg",
            "ProductSize": "FREE",
            "ProductColor": "#0c1155",
            "ProductRate": "409",
            "Quantity": "1",
            "ProductTotal": "409"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: could you provide sample json for this api?

Comment: Hey, I just Add my JSON response.  When First my app start the `"ProductList"` is empty.. Thats why the error I guess. If you just help me out to handle this error

Comment: when you are getting empty list does `ProductList:[]` as field in json??

Comment: Yes , `ProductList:[]` as field in json .. Initially when my app first start or user remove all item form list (Shopping Cart) then my `ProductList:[]` empty , and the error happens Sometimes this error does not bother. But I want to handle this error .

Comment: i under stand your problem it was happen to me few days ago, it was error from backend side sometimes one field was not coming from backend in json response, so check for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check like this:

```
      productList: json["ProductList"] == null ? [] :
      List<ProductList>.from(json["ProductList"].map((x)
      =>ProductList.fromJson(x)
```

Comment: I think thats exactly gonna help !!